# AD620 doesn't amplify signal between 1-60mv

Tags: amplifier, analog, measurement, instrumentation-amplifier

I want to amplify a differential voltage signal between 1-60mV usign [AD620](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD620.pdf). But I don't understand why it doesn't work. If I remove Rg I must have gain=1, instead I have a gain smaller than 1.
I connected the input REF to ground and it has a suppy +/-15V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEBxyn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: we need a schematic, and all the measured voltage values from which you computed the gain.

Comment: No, we need a diagram of how you wired up the entire circuit and where you took measurements.  What does <1 mean? And what is the signal input source?

Comment: Anto, you have the power polarity correct, ignore Chupathingy. What you haven't done is told us the voltage on each -in and +in terminal, and how that voltage is controlled to remain within the common mode input range of the 620. If it isn't, that could be your problem.

Comment: @Neil_UK the voltage between in+ and in- terminal comes from shunt resistor and it changes from 0 to 60mV. Because the shunt resistor has the following feature 60mV @ 60A

Comment: @PaulUszak the current that flows in the shunt comes from the power supply or the eletronic load, both connected to the battery. So the current can be positive or negative.

Comment: Unfortunately down voted.  1)  Where does the electricity come from in the shunt? No circuit.   2) The output is floating - how has 1mV been measured? 3) How has 60 mV been measured - was 60 A of current supplied? 4) How is whatever circuitry surrounding the shunt connected to this circuitry?  Common ground etc.?  5) What is the shunt exactly?  There's a lot missing here to speculate on why it's not working...

Comment: @PaulUszak 1) The electricity in the shunt come from a power supply or electronic  load, depending if I want to charge or disharge the battery.
2)I measured the output using a multimeter
3)60mV correspond to 60A, which is the maximum current that can flow in the shunt
4)There is no connection between the shunt circuit with the measurement circuit
5) the shunt is this one https://www.distrelec.ch/en/shunt-with-socket-60-60-mv-gossen-metrawatt-1700v7230/p/17697325?q=shunt+resistor&page=1&origPos=1&origPageSize=25&simi=0.0

Comment: Source V1 is still upside down in your schematic.  If it is that way on your real circuit, then it will not work.  Correct the diagram, and check to be sure how you've wired the real device.

Comment: @JRE: Actually, it isn't. Since the voltage is specified as "-15V", that makes the "+" terminal negative with respect to the "-" terminal. Yes, it's confusing, but it is technically correct.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest that your problem may be that the input is floating - that is, it is not referenced to any voltage level in the AD620. Assuming that your battery is floating (including the charger and the load), then you want to do something like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXxcaf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R2 is inserted just on the off chance that your battery/charger/load is not actually isolated from the AD620 ground, and will prevent large currents from flowing if there is a condition. In the worst case, such as you are using a non-isolated power supply somewhere in the chain, you might well get significant (even full AC) applied to the AD620.

Comment: This is all a complete assumption, putting your circuit into the OP's mouth.

Comment: @PaulUszak - Are you saying that it does not explain the problem? And please read the first sentence again. Notice the use of "may"? Please reconsider your downvote.

Comment: What you mean is  that I have to connect a resistor between the ground of battery and one of terminal of shunt, right?

Comment: No, connect the resistor between the low end of the shunt and the  ground of the AD620 power supply (+/- 15). The ground symbol you used in your post. I do not know how your system is connected, so I cannot tell if your shunt is connected to the battery ground. For all I know, it's connected to the battery + terminal - it's called high-side current monitoring.

Comment: It'is connected to battery - terminal, could it be a problem?

Comment: I have no idea if that is a problem, since I don't know what else your battery/load/charger is connected to. You did not include that on your schematic, and your description in comment is not revealing. Look at your schematic. Connect a 1k resistor from the top of the shunt (V- on the AD620) to the ground which you have shown (for instance, Vref on the AD620). I assume you want a positive output from the AD620. If you are connecting the bottom of the shunt to the battery ground, you will get a negative output, since you have connected that point to the - input of the AD620

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast it works now, but there is another problem. When I insert Rg to add a gain, this gain is not constant. It change when small value of current are flowing, that means voltage drop over the shunt of 29mV(3A).

Comment: Almost certainly it does not, and almost certainly you are ignoring the effects of input offset voltage in the AD620. I suggest you start another question to deal with this. And this time provide far more information about your problem than you did with this one.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast the input offset is 30uV(TYP) and 125uV(MAX)

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast please look at the updated schematic

Comment: As shown in the updated schematic, your AD620 will be negative. If that is OK with you, it's OK with me. Otherwise, please start a new question to deal with any further issues.